# How to register IHubContext<,> in Grace IOC

Tags: .net-core, ioc-container, grace-ioc

I have a 2.2 .net core application, using SignalR core, in one of my Controllers I want to inject `IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient>`. Works pretty well with built-in IoC, but when I add `Grace IoC` I get the following error message:

```sh
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`2[Test.Hubs.ChatHub,Test.Hubs.IChatClient]' while attempting to activate TestController
```

I tried to add the following line in the `ConfigureContainer` method:

```cs
scope.Configure(c=> c.Export<IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient>>());
```

Also tried:

```cs
scope.Configure(c=> { c.Export(typeof(IHubContext<,>)); });
```

Then the error changed to the following which sounds reasonable since I haven't registered a concrete class for the interface.

```sh
Could not find public constructor on type Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`2[[Test.Hubs.ChatHub, Test, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Test.Hubs.IChatClient, Test, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

And BTW, I've tested aforementioned approaches with both 
`.UseGrace((new InjectionScopeConfiguration { AutoRegisterUnknown = true }))` and `.UseGrace((new InjectionScopeConfiguration { AutoRegisterUnknown = false }))`.

`Grace.AspNetCore.MVC` and `Grace.AspNetCore.Hosting` packages are installed.

Anything that I missed?

Comment: So why not add it to service collection like normal in startup and have framework transfer it over to grace container?

Comment: How should I do that, I couldn’t find a concrete public implementation for IHubContext<THub,T>. I mostly go the same way you mentioned unless I need advanced features, which in this case I didn’t.

Comment: You stated it works with built in IoC. How do you do it with built in?

Comment: It automatically detects it, there is no need to register anything manually.

Comment: No it won't. You call a method that adds it. Just need to find that method to see how it does it so you can do it yourself.

Comment: If that’s the case, so adding Grace shouldn’t break anything, because it’s already added by the built-in methods that I haven’t changed. And grace will also use already registered ones. But in my case, I changed nothing, just added Grace.

Comment: For viewers, this is a bug, and you can follow it from [here](https://github.com/ipjohnson/Grace/issues/229)